# Can I add a widget to the <head> of my site?

Tags: widgets, html

I need to add a small bit of JavaScript to the `<head>` section of my site (on every page). I thought Widgets would cover this but I am only able to add widgets to the sidebar and nowhere else.

I've searched around a bit and [one solution on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849057/adding-script-to-wordpress-in-head-elemen) appears to be modifying the functions.php file in my theme. The problem I have with this is that I am using a standard WP theme (Twenty Twelve) so unless I am mistaken, any theme updates would overwrite my changes to the file.

I'm sure I must be missing something simple... I don't really understand why widgets can only go in the sidebar. That's different to every other system I've used.

Comment: In that case, you can rely on this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17362106/1743124).

Comment: Widgets are designed for output so you'd have to keep in mind that a user could put *any* widget into *any* sidebar or widget area. Obviously you wouldn't want someone to put a search bar in the `<head>` as it would break the site! You can add extra widget areas either via a plugin or a child theme. The typical approach to this problem is to extend a settings page via the settings API or create a theme options page with a textarea for custom area. Many off the shelf themes have something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a closer look at the answer Mayeenul suggested, and with a combination of that and the top answer I got it to work. Seems like a custom plugin is the way to go, and much easier than I expected to implement.

First I created a folder at inside `wp-content/plugins/sv-custom-head` (using my initials to avoid conflicts) then added one plugins.php file, with this content:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: SV Custom Head
Description: Description
Version: 1.0
Author:
Author URI:
Plugin URI:
*/

function sv_custom_head()
{
?>
    <script>
    (my code)
    </script>
<?php
}

add_action('wp_head', 'sv_custom_head');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. My plugin [Magic Widgets](http://wordpress.org/plugins/magic-widgets/) works this way. It registers a “sidebar” for `wp_head`, and calls `dynamic_sidebar()` when this action fires.

I use it to add tracking code or `style` elements to the output. You just must be careful not to use any regular widget, because they would create invalid HTML. My plugin comes with a custom widget that ignores the normal widget parameters and print just out what you put in in the widget manager page.